# How to read fixed length array decimals from parquet files correctly?

Tags: c++, parquet

I use the apache parquet-cpp library to read parquet files.
When I read decimal values of a fixed length array physical type, I seem to get an extra byte which seems (I think) to specify if the number is negative.
I can't seem to find documentation about this. I am also not sure why its needed as the number is already a two's complement number. So it's signed anyway.

Here's an example:
a negative number which can be expressed in 8 bytes like so: CE8DFDC498D5D5F5
will be expressed in 9 bytes like so: FFCE8DFDC498D5D5F5

Does anyone know why this could be? Are there official resources on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track for negative values but FF is not a negative indicator it is a sign extension (for a positive number you would have a leading 0x00). Since the values are fixed width, negative values need to be sign-extended to preserve there interpretation in 2-complement.   The actual byte width used by parquet-cpp when writing the file  is determined by the precision of the decimal value stored.  The byte width on reading is fixed by the file.

Comment: Is this official? Where does it specify that in the parquet documentation?

Comment: Also, not quite sure what you mean by "sign extension". Why is it needed if the value is represented in two's complement, as the most significant bit indicates sign?
Does that also mean that if a value can be expressed in less bytes than the precision dictates, then I can expect to see more FF preceding bytes?
Is this extension always added?

Comment: "This" could mean a number of things.  The parquet [decimal documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#decimal) doesn't cover the in's and outs of two's complement math.   Sign extension is the additional sign bytes needed to correctly represent a given number that can be expressed a less bytes at a certain byte length.  For instance -1 in one byte is 0xFF at two bytes it is 0xFFFF, etc.

Comment: As I read the spec there is nothing stopping from having a larger fixed width type than is required by precision. However, please open up a bug as it is wasting storage. If more bytes are written then precision dictates I would expect them to  be sign extended correctly to preserve the algorithm of comparison described in the specification.  Also note, that there was a long standing bug that in the parquet-cpp implementation that was [fixed earlier this year](https://github.com/apache/arrow/commit/79d1f44911fee504c0eeb76ff9c5b669f96da770) when comparing decimal  for parquet statistics purposes